# akka PubSub not working across distributed system

Tags: scala, akka, publish-subscribe, distributed, akka-stream

I have a system that is clustered deploy on k8s, it will have multiple instances when it's deployed.
My code sample like below

```
import akka.actor.typed.pubsub.Topic
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}

object ClusterSystem extends App {
  private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  ActorSystem(
    Behaviors.setup[Unit] { context =>
      implicit val system: ActorSystem[_]           = context.system
      implicit val ex: ExecutionContext             = system.executionContext
      implicit val clusterSharding: ClusterSharding = ClusterSharding(system)

      val pubSubRef: ActorRef[Topic.Command[Message]] = context.spawn(Topic[VendorData].  ("cluster-message"), "ClusterMessage")

      val publishService = new PublisherService(pubSubRef)
      val subscribeService = new SubscribeService(pubSubRef)

      Behaviors.empty
},
    "ClusterSystem"
  )
}
```

PublisherService:

```
import akka.actor.typed.pubsub.Topic

class PublisherService(pubSubRef:ActorRef[Topic.Command[Message]]){
   def publish():Future[Done]={
     for{
      _<- Future.unit
      _ = pubSubRef ! Topic.Publish(Message("someRandomData"))
     } yield Done
   }
}
```

SubscribeService:

```
import akka.actor.typed.pubsub.Topic
import akka.stream.typed.scaladsl.PubSub

class SubscribeService(pubSubRef:ActorRef[Topic.Command[Message]]){
   def subscribe():Source[Message, NotUsed]= PubSub.source(pubSubRef, bufferSize = 10, overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropHead)
}
```

What I expecting is I can get all the message from the subscribe API, but right now, I only can get the message that published on each node.
Example:
instance-1 published message : M-1, M-2
instance-2 published message : M-3, M-4
Expecting:
connect to the instance-1's subscribe api, and I got message: M-1, M-2, M-3, M-4

Comment: Are you sure that the cluster is up (with both nodes joined) before calling `subscribe()` and `publish()`?  Remember that DPS is at-most-once, which means (among other things) that if a message is published before a subscriber has subscribed, that subscriber won't get it and the message won't be delivered to nodes which haven't joined the cluster until after it was published.

Comment: We using k8s to manage the cluster thing, so I'm not sure how the k8s do on cluster config, but in the k8s, I can see both two node pods are running, and there 
 are akka node joined logs printed when both two nodes started. And I'm sure there is only one subscriber for this cluster.

Comment: Finally solved this problem, code has no problem, the reason it's not working is because Message not serialized, it cause an error when other node sends the message to the topic